# ngModel does not update parent object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to make a directive using that requires `ngModel` to manage a coords object (`{x: number, y: number}`).

My problem is when I update the value of in my directive, all works fine the directive, but the parent scope where the data originally comes from is not updated.

In my directive here is the content of the `link` function (only the part that manages ngModel) :

```
ngModel.$render = function() {
    console.log('render');
    scope.top = ngModel.$viewValue.top;
    scope.left = ngModel.$viewValue.left;
};

// Transform model value to view value
// We have x, y coords (of the center) and we need to transform them to a top, left position
ngModel.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
    console.log('> view');
    if (modelValue) {
        return {
            top: modelValue.y - scope.pointer.size / 2,
            left: modelValue.x - scope.pointer.size / 2
        };
    }

    return modelValue;
});

// Transform view value into model value
// We have a top, left position and we need to transform them to x, y coords (of the center)
ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
    console.log('> model');
    if (viewValue) {
        return {
            x: viewValue.left + (scope.pointer.size / 2),
            y: viewValue.top + (scope.pointer.size / 2)
        };
    }

    return viewValue;
});
```

There is a drag'n'drop feature which changes the `$viewValue` and propagate it (when the element is dropped) :

```
scope.$apply(function () {
    ngModel.$setViewValue({
        top: scope.top,
        left: scope.left
    });
});
```

And the directive call in the parent :

```
<img-pointer data-ng-repeat="answer in graphicQuestionCtrl.answer"
             data-ng-model="answer">
</img-pointer>
```

The value in `graphicQuestionCtrl.answer` seems to never be updated.

I have removed the isolated scope from the directive `img-pointer` as I have read it blocks the update of parent, but it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Most common problem is breaking the golden rule of always using an object in `ng-model` since primitives in child scopes will lose 2 way binding

Comment: The `answer` var actually is an object : `{x: 10, y: 20}`. Also, in the directive `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` are correctly updated.

Comment: Not as scope object passed to view if you don't have a *dot* in it .... always always have a dot in ng-model

Comment: Good point. But I'm not sure how I can do it, as if I pass the whole array I will not be able to retrieve the correct object in it. And if I try to pass the `$index` to the directive, I will need an isolate scope and it seems it also breaks ngModel propagation.

Comment: Hard to really help without a demo that replicates problem

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try to add a sub object and so I can do `data-ng-model="answer.coords"` (or maybe better as it doesn't change my data structure `data-ng-model="graphicQuestionCtrl.answer[$index]"`). If you are right, it will fix the problem.

Comment: You are right using `data-ng-model="graphicQuestionCtrl.answer[$index]"` seems to fix the problem. Post your comment as answer so I will be able to mark this as closed. Thanks a lot.